# Getting AAPT error: check logs for details

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aapt, aapt2

[image]

Every time I have running my project I received this error, despite I put it:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: this is usually because of incorrect drawable. Please check your drawable throughly, especially nine patch drawable.

Answer (score 9):

Inside the build window, where you can see the tree with red and green circles - notice that on the left panel there's a green hammer? Just under it is an icon to change the tree view to the gradle console output. Please click that icon and scroll through the logs - the AAPT errors should be in there.

Comment: Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE

Comment: :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date

Comment: It looks like the log got truncated. The errors should be between the first and the second commend you posted. You can also go to your project directory and run "/.gradlew clean :app:mergeDebugResources" and update the post question to contain the whole output.